# Terminal error in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, crash

I have a small problem with my terminal in Ubuntu 10.04. Normally when I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> it will change to full screen terminal mode. But, in my case it doesn't work and the screen just goes black.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens if you use Ctrl+Alt+F2?

Comment: the same is accoured 
only black screen..

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10085888&postcount=20

Comment: @Linger When editing posts, please use the <kbd> tag for highlighting keyboard keys. Backticks are for things like computer code and console commands.

Comment: @Indrek, will do.  I totally forgot about the keyboard keys

Answer (score 1):

When you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> you will go the tty1, that's like another instance of the computer that only uses the terminal.

You will need to login to enter, go back type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>. If you use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gnome-terminal`, then press <kbd>F11</kbd>, it will be in full screen.

Comment: I'm sure that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to help ...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is a problem with the framebuffer.  In your grub configuration file add this to the kernel boot parameters: `vga=normal.` If you do not have access to the grub file then you can add the line as a test at boot. If the problem is with the framebuffer this may fix it.

vga=normal simply starts up a normal VGA console instead of a framebuffer one.